# Using a While loop to generate ints to append?

Tags: python

What I want to have is a while loop run and generate a random list of a random amount of ints.

```
import random

randAmount = random.randint(15,20)
randNumber = random.randint(2,5)
numbList = []

lookFor = 3

while len(numbList) < randAmount:
    numbList.append(randNumber)
```

my output:

```
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

What can I do in order to have the `randNumber` repeat different numbers?

Note: It is okay if numbers would repeat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only called `randint()` *once* to generate `randNumber`. If you wanted to generate *different* random numbers you need to keep calling it, in the loop:

```
while len(numbList) < randAmount:
    numbList.append(random.randint(2,5))
```

You could use a list comprehension instead of a `while` loop here;

```
numbList = [random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(random.randint(15, 20))]
```

Quick demo of the latter approach:

```
>>> import random
>>> [random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(random.randint(15, 20))]
[2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3]
>>> [random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(random.randint(15, 20))]
[2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 4, 3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5]
>>> [random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(random.randint(15, 20))]
[5, 2, 5, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2]
>>> [random.randint(2, 5) for _ in range(random.randint(15, 20))]
[3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 4, 2, 5, 5, 4, 2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a function instead of a value.

```
randNumber = lambda: random.randint(2,5)
```

Then call that function each time.

```
numbList.append(randNumber())
```